# Not Found proxy.cgi file

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I have a problem with proxy.cgi. I read other posts but didn't find a solution. When I make my WFS request in console, the following error comes up: "POST http:// localhost:8081/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fgeoserver%2Fwfs 404 (Not Found)", in other words the application don't find my proxy.cgi file. My settings are:

- OpenLayers.ProxyHost="/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=" in OpenLayers.js;
- uncomment tag servlet and servlet-mapping in web.xml file of server Tomcat;
- add privileged="true" attribute to tag Context in context.xml of server Tomcat;
- change first row of proxy.cgi in #!C:/Python27/python.exe (installation path on Windows 7).

Any idea how to resolve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Is proxy.gci executable?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the webserver that you are using, so I'll talk about the general steps.

A 404 error means that your proxy.cgi file is not found by your webserver.

1. Can you access the proxy.cgi file in your browser? Open the link http:// localhost:8081/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi and see what happens.
2. Is your server properly configured to work with cgi? You have mentioned Tomcat in your question, so have a look at this page: [CGI How To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cgi-howto.html)

Once you can access the proxy.cgi, make sure that you have edited the proxy.cgi file to provide access to your Geoserver.

Comment: Hi Devdatta, thanks for your reply. I haven't access to proxy.cgi file in my browser, i have the 404 error. However, i configured proxy.cgi file (add 'http://localhost:8080' to allowedHosts variable, because geoserver run on localhost:8080) and server (uncomment tag servlet and servlet-mapping in web.xml file of server Tomcat). I don't understand why this anomaly. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks fot your reply. In the first row of my proxy.cgi file i wrote the installation path of python( #!/usr/bin/env python) and launch python before my application. Are there others step? If, yes, what are they? Thanks again.

Comment: @Riccardo You need to make sure that your webserver supports cgi files. Can you tell me which webserver are you using?

Comment: Devdatta my webserver is Apache Tomcat version 6.0.33

Comment: @Riccardo Follow these steps to enable cgi http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cgi-howto.html

Comment: I followed all steps, in my web.xml i remove comments from servlet and servlet-mapping tags; value tags are:                                          cgi-> org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet
debug-> 0
cgiPathPrefix-> WEB-INF/cgi, 
executable-> C:/Python27/python.exe, 
passShellEnvironment-> true,    
load-on-startup-> 5, 

servlet-name-> cgi, 
url-pattern-> /cgi-bin/*.                                                                                             And add privileged="true" attribute to tag Context in context.xml.

Comment: In this guide http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions there are some steps for Unix machine. I use Apache Tomcat 6, the unix path /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ corrisponds to windows path C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\lib? Thanks